# SVN error to checkout from Eclipse folder doesnt exist

Tags: eclipse, svn, ssh, centos

Im installed svn server in Centos 6.6 via ssh

Then i imported some file
svn import /var/www file:///var/svn/myfiles -m "initial import"

I can see my repository on the URL but when i tried to check out the project via svn on eclipse i got the error Folder doesnt exist remotely
Here its the url of my  [repository](http://cerrajerianecochea.com.ar/svn/mgcerrajeria/)
I search this error in stackoverflow but the solutions wasn't succesfull for me

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem but following this [Link](https://www.krizna.com/centos/install-svn-server-on-centos-6/) i could make the svn repository on centos via ssh

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the IBM Rational Application Development Eclips then please follow below instruction

Window->Preferences->Team->SVN Then select 'SVN Interface' as 'SVNKit(Pure Java)svnkIT'. Click 'Apply' and then 'OK'.